# Using google translate with my own

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-translate

I am using google translate element: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools for my entire website. I place the code generated in the master file so it is available on every page. Now, I have a few page where I do not want to use google's translation but my own. I am able to prevent the google from not translating a certain control, but now I have two drop downs box showing on my page. How can I get rid of one? either catching the value of the language selected in the googles dropdown or by somehow passing my own dropdowns value to the google dropdown and trigger a change. I have not been able to do either of them. I would appreciate any help here.

Thanks,
Ratan

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to hide or remove google translator from some of your website pages, follow the following steps.

i: Place your google translator code e.g in asp.net panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
     google translator code
</asp:Panel>
```

ii: On load or pre render event of page where you want to hide google translator code use the following code.

```
MasterPage mstr = Page.Master;
Panel pnl = (Panel)mstr.FindControl("pnl");
pnl.Visible = false;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have suppose three controls on my page. I want to use google translate for two of them and use my own translator for the third one. I am able to do that, but the user has to use two different dropdown. I want to link googles dropdown to be able to fire my own transltion as well.